# how to solve " non-static variable shelf cannot be referenced from a static context" error?

Tags: java, class, static, console-application

I am creating a simple Jave console application. So I am using few classes in different files. I need to set some parameters for the class instance and retrieve it later. but it gives me following error. Please help me to solve it.

**Main Class**

```
public class Main {

    private Student student = new Student();   

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        student.setName("John");
            //Java: non-static variable student cannot be referenced from a static context

    }
}
```

**Student Class**

```
public class Student {

    private String name;

     public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        name = name;
    }
}
```

**How can I avoid this issue ? Please help**

Comment: There's no *instance* of `Main` available in the function `main`.

Comment: declare variable student as static

Comment: This is  a classic newbie error, a `static` method can be called directly from a class. Anything which is not static needs to be called from an instance Object of the class.

Your Field `private Student student = new Student();` only exists for an instance object of Main. Like:

    public class Main {
    
        private Student student = new Student();   
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Main main = new Main();
            main.student.setName("John");

        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student student = new Student();   
        student.setName("John");
    }
}
```

You could have declared that private data member as static, but there's no reason for a class member at all.  This class is nothing more than a driver.  Better to instantiate all the objects it needs inside the main method.

Do yourself a favor and learn the [Java coding standards](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html).  You are not following them in this code.

Comment: Why on earth is this downvoted?  It's perfectly correct.

Comment: I haven't voted, but these votes reflect usefulness, not necessarily correctness.

Comment: Usefulness?  I think the OP should judge that.  Just learning about the Java coding standards is worth the price of admission alone.  Simple answers can still be useful to the person asking.

Comment: You might haven't noticed yet, but you don't answer for OP alone and Stack Overflow isn't a help desk, thus helpfulness obivously also considers future readers.

Comment: I don't need instruction, especially not from you; I've been here long enough to know how it works.  SO is a Q&A site for programmers.  A user posted a question; I gave an answer.  It's not the first or the last time that someone who's not familiar with Java will get confused about static and non-static.  Do you make a contribution here besides trollish comments?  Or do you answer questions, too?

Comment: If a question is worth an answer (not a dupe, clear, useful and not answered yet), then I'll answer it. **"I've been here long enough to know how it works."** your third comment proved your wrong :/. But nevermind, no need to continue that discussion.

Comment: We'll all look forward to that.  Not many questions appear to have met your high standards in the three years you've been here.  (PS - I believe it's "proved", not "proofed".  I know how it works.)

Comment: Yes that's true and kind of sad that these rules are considered "high standard" and not "default" for a community who tries to create high quality content.

Comment: I think the community has done very well without you.   Sad?  Not at all.  Stack Exchange is doing very well, indeed.